# LINQ Include method run-time error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, include

I’m working with 
Visual Studio 2017 Express, 
ASP.NET Core 1.1
EntityFramework 1.0.0 , 
Microsoft .Net Framework 4.7.02046, 
SQL Server  2012 LocalDB

I’m experienced in app & DB developing. I’m newbie with this tech. I’ve read many docs & courses making a good experience. Now I´m developing my first real app.
I apologize for my English.

**The problem**
There are 4 tables:
[The relations][1]

1) This Works OK: let me show a list of Paciente with the list of Reserva for each one.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var paciente = await _context.Pacientes
            .Include(p => p.Reservas)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.PacienteID == id);
        if (paciente == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(paciente);
    }
```

2) This gives a runtime error:
SqlException: Invalid object name 'ProfesionalPorReserva'.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var profesional = await _context.Profesionales
          .Include(p => p.ProfesionalPorReservas)  //this line is the problem
            .AsNoTracking()
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
        if (profesional == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(profesional);
    }
```

3) Same problema as 2)
 SqlException: Invalid object name 'ProfesionalPorReserva'.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var reserva = await _context.Reservas
           // .Include(r => r.ProfesionalPorReservas)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ReservaID == id);
        if (reserva == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(reserva);
    }
```

I fixed the problem adding, as sugested the IntelligentSense:

```
var reserva = await _context.Reservas
   .Include(r => r.ProfesionalPorReservas)
           .ThenInclude( navigationPropertyPath: p => p.Profesional)
   .Include(r => r.ProfesionalPorReservas)
            .ThenInclude(navigationPropertyPath: r => r.Rol)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ReservaID == id);
```

adding **navigationPropertyPath:** was the solution.

Comment: Can you show the code for the dbcontext class (`_context`)

Comment: I fixed the problem. It worked. I'd explain how at the end of my question. Thanks for your answer.